# jps 'process information unavailable'

Tags: java, linux, hadoop

I've installed Hadoop 3.2.4 on ubuntu 20.04 with openjdk version "11.0.17". and it's worked successfully few days.
suddenly, when I use jps command, the output is like this.

```
ubuntu@server1:/tmp$ jps
653257 -- process information unavailable
655002 -- process information unavailable
654220 -- process information unavailable
654065 -- process information unavailable
654387 -- process information unavailable
653810 -- process information unavailable
653412 -- process information unavailable
```

### Already tried

1. remove hsperfdata_ubuntu directory
2. chmod 755 hsperfdata_ubuntu
   It's worked. but after a few minutes, hsperfdata_ubuntu directory changed automatically permission from 755 to 777. I don't know why
3. try to jps command when su

```
root@server1:/tmp# jps
653257 -- process information unavailable
655002 -- process information unavailable
656601 Jps
654220 -- process information unavailable
654065 -- process information unavailable
654387 -- process information unavailable
653810 -- process information unavailable
653412 -- process information unavailable
```

### another problems

sometimes the shell displayed "Killed" when processed python script.

Comment: `jps` shows Java processes. What do you mean "python script"?

Comment: No, I mean java processes. I was running Hadoop, so I use the 'jps' command

Comment: Then I don't understand last sentence of your post. Okay, well, Hadoop 3.2.4 doesn't support Java 11, last I checked, only 3.3.4 added it https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r3.3.4/index.html

Comment: ohwow, you're right. It's worked after changed java version from 11 to 8. THANKS!!!

Comment: Ideally, you should upgrade to the latest version of Hadoop, instead.

Comment: Could you tell me why? just to use the java 11?

Comment: Correct. Java 8 is end-of-life has will have security vulnerabilities, as well as Hadoop itself

Comment: Okay, I'm gonna upgrade Hadoop and Java version. thanks

Comment: Hello again. I upgraded Hadoop 3.3.4 and Java 11 version. But, `process information unavailable` error happened again,, I don't know what should I do. Could you tell me just anything to help me?

Comment: Never mind! I uninstalled java 8 version. and it works~